# implicit declaration of a function compiles in gcc but not in g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have the following C code with a missing function

`test1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 Log("hello");
 return 0;
}
```

Compiling it to an object file with `gcc -c test1.c` produces an object file with a warning (linking will fail of course).

Compiling the same code (with iostream instead of stdio.h) to an object file using `g++` doesn't even compile and it complains by `error: use of undeclared identifier 'Log'`. 
Why didn't gcc stop compilation but g++ did?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. GCC seems to select the language based on how you invoke it.

Comment: what's with the downvotes?

Comment: @KeithThompson I am sorry, I will delete my comment and give an upvote for the question. :) :D

Comment: The question did produce a couple of decent answers, but the pop-up help when you hover the mouse over the down arrow is a pretty good answer: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.* The question is clear and usefulness can be debated, but what's likely pulling in the downvotes is lack of research. C and C++ are like American Football and Rugby. They look kinda similar and share some common rules, but I was surprised the first time I saw that in Rugby "touchdown" was meant literally.

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not permit undeclared functions to be called. However, prior to C99, undeclared functions are sometimes permitted in C. Therefore, the code has to result in compile time error in C++, but it can succeed in compiling in C89 (although linking will find no definition of the hypothetical `Log`.)

Since C99, undeclared functions are not permitted.

Answer (score 3):

Because C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

There is no such thing as an implicit function declaration in C++ and there never has been in any version of the language standard. The shown program is ill-formed.

Non-declared functions can be called in old versions of C. However, since C99 it has been ill-formed in that language as well.

Comment: To be precise, in C99 and later a call to an undeclared function is a *constraint violation*. A conforming compiler must diagnose it, but the diagnostic can be a non-fatal warning. gcc is not a conforming compiler by default, though its behavior in this particular case is conforming.